# meaning of *Supports network install?* and *Works "out of the box"*

Tags: helpfile

What do **Supports network install?** and **Works "out of the box"** mean in this page:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsDlink

Does *network install* mean that it supports creating a network connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "network install" is something that an administrator can do from a remote computer, as soon as the physical network card has been placed into the local computer. The advantage then is that the administrator does not have to come round to the local machine to install drivers or other software. This would be useful if a large number of systems in a wide geographic area are to be installed with new hardware.
For this, the local computer would then need either a second network card that already works, or the network card would need to "work out of the box", meaning: would work without installing additional drivers. (The image is of you taking a brand new network card out of the box that you bought it in, placing it in the machine, and noticing that it works straightaway). In the latter case, it is possible that the network card works well enough to connect to the network, but perhaps not with all available features.